# How to get a list of all classes in a .kt file

Tags: java, reflection, jvm, kotlin

Is it possible to grab a list of classes inside a .kt file? It appears that KDeclarationContainer is the class I am looking for, but I am unsure of how to use it.

EDIT: I am using Kotlin Reflection.

Comment: Please add more details: are you using Kotlin reflection for this or writing an extension to the IDE/compiler?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to obtain all classes which were declared in a specific .kt source file at runtime via reflection API, in much the same way as it's impossible to get all Java classes in a .java source file with Java reflection API. This information is simply not available at runtime.

What is your use case? I think if you're relying on something like that, your best workaround is to declare your classes inside one top-level class, and call `KClass#nestedClasses` to get them all at runtime.